Pagination on the result from multiple collection .net
I am trying to add offset pagination( input is pagesize and limit)  on combined result which is aggregating multiple collections. Earlier I had only limit on the reponse. Below is the code for the API function
private readonly IMongoCollection<Definition> _sharedMongoCollection;
    private IMongoQueryable<Definition> SharedDbQueryableCollection { get; }
    private readonly IMongoCollection<Definition> _otherMongoCollection;
    private IMongoQueryable<Definition> otherDbQueryableCollection { get; }

        SharedDbQueryableCollection = _sharedMongoCollection.AsQueryable();
        otherDbQueryableCollection = _otherMongoCollection.AsQueryable();

      public async Task<IEnumerable<Definition>> GetAllAsync(Context context, string filterCondition,
        uint? limit)
    {
        var sharedQuery = SharedDbQueryableCollection
            .ApplyContext(context, _scopeConditionEnforcement)
            .ApplyFilter(filterCondition, _scopeConditionEnforcement);
        var otherQuery = otherDbQueryableCollection
            .ApplyContext(context, _scopeConditionEnforcement)
            .ApplyFilter(filterCondition, _scopeConditionEnforcement);

        var sharedResult = _mongoDbRepository.GetAllAsync(sharedQuery);
        var tenantResult = _mongoDbRepository.GetAllAsync(tenantQuery);
        var result = (await Task.WhenAll(sharedResult, tenantResult))
            .SelectMany(t => t).ToList();
        return limit.HasValue ? result.Take((int)limit.Value) : result;
    }

What approach should I choose for offset pagination.

Take and Skip and OrderBy should be part of your query, and not after ToList.

If I use take and skip at the combined result, I have to fetch all the document in memory first and then apply pagination. What could be my approach to apply pagination on the given code

you have to fix your query to get both results in a single call. So, sharedQuery and otherQuery must be combined, then append the pagination to the combined query, then call GetAllAsync once.

but they are fetching from different collections. if possible can u suggest cod changes

share the actual code (with the both queries), with the collections models, you can hide any sensitive info from the code. To have a better answer to your question.

The code is same on question, I need to apply pagination where i have input parameters as page and limit

sharedQuery  and otherQuery and sharedResult and otherResult and SharedDbQueryableCollection and otherDbQueryableCollection ... no clue about their types, and what they actually represents, except of assuming they're all related entities. if you don't add more context to your question, you will never have a good answer.

Updated the code with Entities. Basically both queries are fetching same enitity but from different collection. Previously I was only using limit on the result but now I have to apply pagination. I am not sure how should I apply that

Both sharedQuery and otherQuery are querying the same entity. Which mean, either your query can be refactored to have a single query that returns the same results by a simple OR operator, or you need a union to fetch both results.
Since we don't have a sample that would give us a better view on the code, I feel showing a Union will be better option for this answer.
If ApplyContext will call DbSet, where it will apply IQueryable extensions by calling ApplyFilter, and returns IQueryable then you can do :
var query = sharedQuery.Union(otherQuery);

if(limit.HasValue)
    query = query.Take((int)limit.Value); 

var result = await query.ToListAsync();

return result;

The idea is to combine both IQueryable expressions and then call Take to be part of that expression, then call ToListAsync to execute that expression against the DBMS. (in your case MongoDB).
This would make a single call to the database with the desired results, instead of multiple calls that would store all results in memory then filtering the results by the limit.
